# scrape data using Nokogiri available in span tag

Tags: javascript, ruby, web-scraping, screen-scraping, nokogiri

How to scrape name and price of the product of the page http://www.tradus.com/t-shirts-tees-reebok-puma-fifa-teesort/t/7682?Type=polo+neck using nokogiri and how to scrape all the product of the category as pagination is there.Following is the code where I am getting the price but in HTML tags and only for 1 page.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.tradus.com/t-shirts-tees-reebok-puma-fifa-teesort/t/7682?  Type=polo+neck"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.css(".prodListing-item").each do |dv|
product_name = dv.at_css('.prod-name').text unless dv.at_css(".prod-name").nil?
product_price = dv.at_css('.price-info span span:nth-child(2)').to_s 
puts product_name + product_price
end
```

Comment: How many pages you want? You should look at the `selenium-webdriver`,to navigate the page and then nokogiri to scrap the page.

Comment: Thanks Arup it got fixed by mentioning the page in the URL and using while loop in it.

Comment: post your code as an answer! I will post my one at night!

Answer (score 1):

```
Following is the code which resolved the issue
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

number=1
while true
url="http://www.tradus.com/t-shirts-tees-reebok-puma-fifa-teesort/t/7682?  Type=polo+neck&page=#{number}"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
products=doc.css(".prodListing-item")
break if products.size == 0
products.each do |item|
product_name = item.at_css('.prod-name').text unless item.at_css(".prod-name").nil?
product_price = item.at_css('.price-info span span:nth-child(2)').text unless     item.at_css(".price-info span span:nth-child(2)").nil?
puts product_name +"<==========>" +product_price
end
puts "page" +"#{number}"
number += 1

end
puts "exit of the while loop"
```